# I am getting a segmentation fault error on my C program

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, gdb

I am getting a segmentation fault in one of the following blocks of code, but I suspect it to be this one, xbits.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

void itox(int n, char hexstring[]);
int xtoi(char hexstring[]);

void itox(int n, char hexstring[]) {
    hexstring[2*sizeof(n) + 1];
    int ratio, remainder;
    int i = 0;
    while(ratio  != 0)
    {

        ratio = n / 16;
        remainder = n % 16;
        if (remainder == 10){
            hexstring[i] = 'A';
            i++;
        }
        else if (remainder == 11){
            hexstring[i] = 'B';
            i++;
        }
        else if (remainder == 12){
            hexstring[i] = 'C';
            i++;
        }
        else if (remainder == 13){
            hexstring[i] = 'D';
            i++;
        }
        else if (remainder == 14){
            hexstring[i] = 'E';
            i++;
        }
        else if (remainder == 15){
            hexstring[i] = 'F';
            i++;
        }
        else 
            hexstring[i] = remainder;

    }   
    i++;
    hexstring[i] = '\0';
}

int xtoi(char hexstring[]) {
    int i, integer;
    int length = getLength(hexstring);
    for (i = length-2 ; i >= 0 ; i--)
    {
         integer += (int) pow((float) hexstring[i] , (float) i);
    }

    return integer;
}

int getLength (char line[])
{
    int i;

    i=0;
    while (line[i])
        ++i;
    return i;
}
```

The above relies on a main method, showxbits.c that I have not debugged yet, but when I used a test main method I got a segmentation fault error, and when I use gdb I get the following error.

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00000000004007ad in itox ()
```

Which leads me to believe that the problem is in itox in the above .c file. The program is supposed to convert an int to hex and a hex back to int.

Comment: You *suspect*? A debugger will tell you the *exact* line.

Comment: gdb told me the error was in itox but not the line the error occurred on.

    (gdb) run
    Starting program: /home/gkendall/showxbits 

    Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
    0x00000000004007ad in itox ()

Comment: Then compile with `-g` to include debuging information. Add `-Wall` to that to see some very informative messages, for example about uninitialised variables.

Comment: Reading this might also help you to help yourself: http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: On the 1st iteration this `while(ratio  != 0)` uses `ratio` uninitialised.

Answer (score 2):

You have many errors in your code. You can catch some of them with compiler warnings. Some of them are logical errors, though.

- `ratio` is uninitialised and will contain garbage when you first use it in the `while` condition. It should probably be initialised to `n`.
- Your `while` loop condition will never change (the initial value aside), because `ratio` will always be `n / 16` and `n` never changes. You probably don't need `ratio` and can work on `n` directly.
- When you say `hexstring[i] = remainder` you don't do what you think you do. You want to assign a digit, but you assign the character with an ASCII code of zero to 9, which are mostly unprintable characters. (Zero even terminates the string.) You want

  ```
  hexstring[i] = '0' + remainder;
  ```

  here. You can do the same for letters with `'A'`. Note that in the case of a digit you don't increment `i`, thus overwriting the digit in the next iteration through the loop.
- The lone line

  ```
  hexstring[2 * sizeof(n) + 1];
  ```

  doesn't do anything. You must allocate enough memory in the function that calls `itox`.
- You are writing the letters to the string in the wrong order.
- When you decode, you shouldn't take the hex digits by their ASCII values. You must convert them to their values from 0 to 15.
- don't use the `pow` function for simple integer arithmetic. Instead, follow the pattern of `itox`, only the other way round: Muliply the result with 16 and add the value of the next hex digit.
- You can, of course, roll your own `strlen` and call it `getLength`, but make sure to provide a prototype before you call it.
- This is a minor issue, but your numbers should proably be `unsigned`, because there is no hex representation of negative ints.

Comment: Also , NUL-terminator is placed in the location ahead of the required location.